# Error: SolanaJSONRPCError code:-32602

Tags: error

When I use my program, 90% of my transactions from the program's instructions pass; but during the 10%, the program throws a SolanaJSONRPCError with -32602 code. Please what does it mean and how can I stop it?

```
{"code":-32602,"name":"SolanaJSONRPCError"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the JSON-RPC spec, -32602 means "invalid params". So somehow, that 10% of the time there is likely something wrong with the request parameters.

https://www.jsonrpc.org/specification#error_object

The `SolanaJSONRPCError` type is defined in `@solana/web3.js` here: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-web3.js/blob/55652a081113c59cf054305a70f5deec268f15f1/src/errors.ts#L34

If you grep for it, you'll see in dozens of places mostly in `web3.js/src/connection.ts`.

I also performed a grep for `-32602` and did not find it the `@solana/web3.js` code.

If you want to stop this error, you're going to need to hunt down the cause of those invalid parameters.